# Is it safe/okay to combine take(1) and defaultIfEmpty when subscribing to Observable<boolean>?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I am using the following code to basically ensure that I get a result from an Observable

```
this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    defaultIfEmpty(false)
  )
  .subscribe(result => return result);
```

Somehow it feels wrong to me, maybe because it seems sort of procedural.

Is this method okay? Will this get me in trouble in any way?

Comment: depends what's happening in `isLoggedIn`... `defaultIfEmpty` only does anything if the source completes without emitting, so that needs to be able to happen in `isLoggedIn` for it to have any effect

Comment: Not sure what your use case is, but I would consider whether you really need to cut it off at one emission. The most reactive way would be recognize the logged in status as a mutable value and write code to respond reactively.

Comment: By the way, you might want to see if ```startWith``` is more what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If in your code it's fine that `this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn` completes without an emit - then the code in your question is fine too.
If `this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn` emits anything at some point of time and completes after - then `defaultIfEmpty` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what `isLoggedIn` does.

It is clear that `isLoggedIn` returns an Observable.

Now, and Observable can do just 3 things

- it can notify, i.e. emit, some data for consumption of Observers which are subscribed
- it can raise an error
- it can complete

So the first question is: how many times can `isLoggedIn` notify? Is it just one shot or is it a stream of notifications? If it can emit just one value and then complete, than the `take(1)` operator is useless.

But there is also the case that `isLoggedIn` never notifies and just completes. In this case a *notification* would never be signaled by the observer to its subscriber. Using `defaultIfEmpty` operator ensures that something is notified even in this case.

So, reading your code I understand that `isLoggedIn` can behave in these 2 ways

1. Emit more than once but you are interested only in the first notification
2. Never notify and just complete, in which case you want `false` to be returned

If this is not true, it may be the case that your code can be simplified.